# msys2 `which` is very slow on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, zsh, msys

The `which` command was never particularly fast, but since I switched to Windows 10, it is extremely slow. I have a generic `.zshrc` that I carry around, so it tests to see if some programs are available before configuring them. And the first few calls take over 10 seconds.

I am using zsh, which has `which` built-in. This *might* make a difference, though defining `which() { /usr/bin/which "%@" }` does not seem to improve anything.

Note: I don't have any network drives mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround and all around nicer approach, given what you're doing in this case, is to avoid using `which` entirely, like so:

```
if (( $+commands[foobar] ))
  # configure foobar
fi
```

#### How does it work?

From `zshexpn(1)`:

> ${+name}
>
> If name is the name of a set parameter '1' is substituted, otherwise '0' is substituted.

`$commands` is an associative array that is managed by *zsh* (also the `hash` builtin) consisting of command names as keys, and their associated path as a value.

So, using the `${+name}` expansion on the `$commands` hash table, indexed by the command you wish to test for the existence of gives you a cheap and fast way to make that check.

Lastly, the `(( expr ))` construct is an arithemetic evaluation, since the `${+name}` expansion returns either 0 or 1.